# Webservices in weblogic9.2

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I have written an Webservice using jax-ws (with Eclipse IDE) and have bundled it in War, in turn bundled within an Ear. I'm able to deploy that fine and testing of the web services also works fine. But when I login to my Weblogic Admin console and expand the Ear deployment, I don't see anything under **'Web services'**, it displays **None to display**.

Could any one please let me know what is that am missing here?

this is the `application.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application id="Application_ID" version="1.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/application_1_4.xsd">
    <display-name>EAR1</display-name>
    <module id="WebModule_1376158300960">
        <web>
            <web-uri>TestWEB.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>TestWEB</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

Comment: What does your application.xml look like? Are you defining `<module>` in it? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/programming/app_xml.html

Comment: Yes I do have module in it and here's how my application.xml under EAR META-iNF looks like,application.xml updated in the main post.